# How to use the ternary operator in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to use ternary operator instead of if else conditions in react.

What i am trying to do?
I have an array of object type named `'list_info'` which has `type`, `recipient_id`and `recipient_email attributes`.

Now i have a method named `"get_text"` which returns text whose value is string "to you" or the recipient email.

```
If the list_info type is "type_1" and props.current_user_id === list_info.recipient_id then it should 
return nothing. 

If the list_info type is "type_1" and props.current_user_id !== list_info.recipient_id then it should 
return the list_info.recipient_email.


Now when the list_info type is anything other than "type_1" and and props.current_user_id === 
list_info.recipient_id then it should 
return string "to you". 

 If the list_info type is anything other than "type_1" and props.current_user_id !== 
 list_info.recipient_id then it should return the list_info.recipient_email.
```

So to accomplish the above conditions i have the "get_text" method as below,

```
get_text = () => {
    const list_info = this.props.list_info;
    let text;
    if (this.props.list_info.type === 'type_1') {
        if (this.props.current_user_id === list_info.recipient_id) {
            text = '';
        } else {
            text = list_info.recipient_email;
        }
    } else {
        text = this.props.current_user_id === list_info.recipient_id
        ? 'you'
        : list_info.recipient_email;
    }
    return <strong key={list_info.type}>{text}</strong>;
};
```

The above code works. But i think it could be made even more simple to read using ternary operator. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Ternary operator isn't more simple to read.

Comment: hmm less code i think.. that works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally writing nested ternary operators will make the code unreadable. You can refactor your code as below, if you have more and more conditions/logic coming in, you can probably start using `switch` statement.

```
get_text = () => {
    const { list_info, current_user_id } = this.props;
    const meTextByType = list_info.type === 'type_1' ? "" : "you";
    let text = current_user_id === list_info.recipient_id ? 
               meTextByType :
               list_info.recipient_email;
    return <strong key={list_info.type}>{text}</strong>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_text = () => {
    const { list_info, current_user_id } = this.props;
    const { type, recipient_id, recipient_email } = list_info;
    const meTextByType = type === 'type_1' ? "" : "you";

    let text = current_user_id === recipient_id ? meTextByType :brecipient_email;
    return <strong key={type}>{text}</strong>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about local functions that describe exactly what each condition is, and by the looks of you only ever return 2 values, either 'to you' or the recipient_email prop.

```
getText = () => {

  const isToYou = () => listInfoType !== 'type_1' && recipientId === userId

  return isToYou() ? 'To You' : recipientEmail

}
```